# Использование AddForce вместе с GetMouseButton(0) в методе FixedUpdate

Tags: c#, unity3d

Поместил такой код в FixedUpdate так как работу с физикой рекомендуется делать не в Update, а в FixedUpdate. Проблема в том, что он срабатывает не корректно. Как это исправить?

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
       //AddForce
    }
}
```

Comment: `так как работу с физикой нужно делать не в Update`. Не `нужно`, а `рекомендуется`, катастрофы не произойдёт. А вот у `Input` в `FixedUpdate` конкретные проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто

Что бы при нажатии перемещать объект, т.е. чтобы переместить - надо нажать

```
private Vector3 force;

private void Update()
{
    //force = Vector3.zero 

    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        //force = ...
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    //.AddForce(force * Time.fixedDeltaTime) по желанию можно добавить ForceMode.Impulse
}
```

Если вы хотите чтобы объект перемещался когда кнопка нажата, то переносим force = Vector3.zero в if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))

```
private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        //force = ...
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        //force = Vector3.zero 
    }
}
```

Если кратко, то для регистрации нажатий рекомендуется использовать Update, а для работы с физикой FixedUpdate. (Вероятнее всего Input некорректно ведёт себя в FixedUpdate! Подскажите если кто знает почему так происходит?!)

Comment: Что значит "ведет себя некорректно"?

Comment: потому что    нажатия клавиш проверяются в каждом кадре, перед update,  а функция fixedUpdate вызывается через фиксированные промежутки времени и может не совпасть с update ,

Comment: ну это грубо говоря